# How to implement WS-SecurityPolicy on the endpoint (server) with JAX-WS Metro?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

I have the following policy in my WSDL file:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" 
   xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
   xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" 
   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
   >
   <wsap:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsap="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"/>
   <sp:SymmetricBinding>
       <wsp:Policy>
           <sp:ProtectionToken>
               <wsp:Policy>
                   <sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
               </wsp:Policy>
           </sp:ProtectionToken>
       </wsp:Policy>
   </sp:SymmetricBinding>
</wsp:Policy>
```

and I have included it in the binding:

```
    <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" URI="#UsernameToken"/>
```

It seem like it passes through the WSDL, except for when in my handler I do:

```
        List<?> securityList = soapEnvelope.getSecurity(null, true);

        if ((securityList == null) || (securityList.size() == 0))
        {
            securityList = soapEnvelope.getSecurity();
        }
```

it returns **null**. soapEnvelop here is: **WSSOAPEnvelope** soapEnvelope, and it's not null;

I would appreciate your help a lot! Have been struggling with this for a while now.

I have a feeling that the security header is being cropped from the envelop.

Also if I remove policy definition from WSDL file, then it passes without `soap:mustUnderstand="1"`, if I do include this attribute then it gives me error message:

```
MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood
```